# Joomla: including php-files renders jdoc-tags unusable

Tags: php, joomla, include

I'm trying to set up a Joomla-template in a way which allows me to use template parameters to choose between a number of layout variations of the template from the admin-interface. The idea is that the index.php only contains a statement which includes a php-file from a folder within the main template folder, based on the template parameters passed.

Unfortunately it seems thatmy jdoc module positions breaks whenever they are located outside the index.php file, even though it is referenced by an include-tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the order that the framework builds index.php. Rather than trying to use include files, you can accomplish the same goal in a much easier and cleaner fashion. Using a combination of collapsible module positions and CSS you can manipulate the template to do basically anything you want.

You can also use template styles if you are using J1.7. A template style is basically a variation of a template that is assigned to specific menu items. Either way will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware it was so easy to do collapsible module positions. I would have preffered though, to have my markup for different purposes separated into individual files, but must admit this is way easier to work with.

Comment: FYI - any markup that you want to run should be coded in to modules. This gives you even more flexibility to control the code including variations based on when and where you are loading the module.